# ImageInputStreamImpl implementation which wraps a byte[]

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I am trying to create an implementation of ImageInputStream which simply wraps a byte[].

This is my implementation, but for some image ImageIO returns error about corrupted data.

I can't find any useful alternative, every subclass of ImageInputStreamImpl bundled with the JDK perform caching and waste memory.

```
public static class MyMemoryCacheImageInputStream extends ImageInputStreamImpl {

        private SimpleByteArrayInputStream stream;

        public MyMemoryCacheImageInputStream(SimpleByteArrayInputStream stream) {
            if (stream == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("stream == null!");
            }
            this.stream = stream;
        }

        @Override
        public int read() throws IOException {
            bitOffset = 0;
            return stream.read();
        }

        @Override
        public void seek(long pos) throws IOException {
            super.seek(pos);
            stream.seek(pos);
        }

        @Override
        public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
            if (b == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException("b == null!");
            }
            if (off < 0 || len < 0 || off + len > b.length || off + len < 0) {
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("off < 0 || len < 0 || off+len > b.length || off+len < 0!");
            }

            bitOffset = 0;

            if (len == 0) {
                return 0;
            }

            return stream.read(b, off, len);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCached() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCachedFile() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCachedMemory() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            super.close();
            stream = null;
        }
    }
```

Please note that SimpleByteArrayInputStream is essentially a ByteArrayInputStream with a "seek" method to modify the internal stream position.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar challenge, and have created an [implementation](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/blob/master/imageio/imageio-core/src/main/java/com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/stream/ByteArrayImageInputStream.java) that is available on GitHub under BSD license. Instead of wrapping a `ByteArrayInputStream` it works directly with a `byte` array.

I haven't tested your implementation, but I believe the main problem with it, is that it doesn't properly update `streamPos` when reading. Seeking seems okay, as you invoke `super.seek(pos)`. The following should fix the problem:

```
@Override
public int read() throws IOException {
    bitOffset = 0;

    int val = stream.read();

    if (val != -1) {
        streamPos++;
    }

    return val;
}

@Override
public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
    if (b == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("b == null!");
    }
    if (off < 0 || len < 0 || off + len > b.length || off + len < 0) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("off < 0 || len < 0 || off+len > b.length || off+len < 0!");
    }

    bitOffset = 0;

    if (len == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    int read = stream.read(b, off, len);

    if (read > 0) {
        streamPos += read;
    }

    return read;
}
```

I believe also that, strictly `isCached()` and `isCachedMemory` should return `true` for your implementation, if it is indeed backed by a `byte` array. But I don't think it matters much (ie. I've never seen code that actually use these methods to optimize anything).

Comment: Thank you @haraldK ! I will use  directly your implementation. You library is great I will evaluate bundling your readers with my application as well.